# Regex decimal number validation ignore validation for minus at first index of string

Tags: java, regex

I have a following regex, which validates decimal number with decimal point.

```
REGEX_VALID_DECIMAL_NUMBER = "\\d+(\\.\\d+)*";
```

So the following numbers are valid according to the pattern:

```
0
0.0
1.00
etc.
```

Issue is, I want to extend my regex so that it ignores the validation "-" case at the first index of the string - for negative numbers.

```
REGEX_VALID_DECIMAL_NUMBER = "[^-\\d+(\\.\\d+)*]";
```

I tried this, by adding ^-, but this will allow everywhere "-":

```
-0-
-0.0-
-1.00-
etc.
```

How can I add that validation for all indexes except first index of string?

Comment: What made you add `[^` and `]`? That's used to define a _character class. Just add `-?` at the front of your expression which means "the dash/minus character zero times or once". And if you don't use `String.matches(...)` then add that `^` to match the start of the input as well, i.e. `^-?\d+ ...`.

Comment: `"^-?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)*$"` at most one minus at the very beginning

Comment: I wanted also to make a regex which will also replace those invalid characters with "" empty string, but that's another question.

Comment: Side note: try to validate `1.1.1.1.1` using your expression. :) Hint: instead of `(\\.\\d+)*` you probably want `(\\.\\d+)?`

Comment: What makes you think a regex is the solution for this? Just use `Double.parseDouble` and see if it throws a `NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use

```
^-?\d+(\.\d+)*$
```

`^-?` will ensure negative is accepted only at the beginning.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vuCeof/1)